# javascript definitive guide exercise 1.2.1

Tags: javascript, html

I'm going through the book JavaScript: A Definitive Guide and I'm having a little difficulty with one of the examples in the book. The idea is to create a loan calculator. If a user inputs data into the form the data is saved and recalled when the user returns to the site/app.

The issue I'm running into is that while that only a portion of the data is being saved and it's showing up in the wrong portions of the form. To be specific, the amount shows up correctly, but apr, years, and zipcode all show up incorrectly. Years shows in apr, zipcode shows up in years, and years shows 'undefined'. I've checked the ids and they all match so I'm not sure why the data is showing up incorrectly. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

This is the JS:

```
function calculate() {
// Look up the input and output elements in the document
var amount        = document.getElementById("amount");
var apr           = document.getElementById("apr");
var years         = document.getElementById("years");
var zipcode       = document.getElementById("zipcode");
var payment       = document.getElementById("payment");
var total         = document.getElementById("total");
var totalinterest = document.getElementById("totalinterest");

var principal = parseFloat(amount.value);
var interest  = parseFloat(apr.value) / 100 / 12;
var payments  = parseFloat(years.value) * 12;

// Now compute the monthly payment figure.
var x       = Math.pow(1 + interest, payments); // Math.pow() computes powers
var monthly = (principal*x*interest)/(x - 1);

if (isFinite(monthly)) {
    // Fill in the output fields, rounding to 2 decimal places
    payment.innerHTML       = monthly.toFixed(2);
    total.innerHTML         = ( monthly * payments ).toFixed(2);
    totalinterest.innerHTML = ( ( monthly * payments ) - principal ).toFixed(2);

    // Save the user's input so we can restore it the next time they visit
    save( amount.value, apr.value, years.value, zipcode.value );

    // Advertise: find and display local lenders, but ignore network errors
    try {                   // Catch any errors that occur within these curly braces...
        getLenders( amount.value, apr.value, years.value, zipcode.value );
    }
    catch(e) { /* ...and ignore those errors  */ }

    // Finally, chart loan balance, and interest and equity payments
    chart( principal, interest, monthly, payments );
    }
else {
    payment.innerHTML       = "";     // Erase the content of these elements
    total.innerHTML         = "";
    totalinterest.innerHTML = "";
    chart();                          // With no arguments, clears the chart
    }
}

function save(amount, apr, years, zipcode) {
if (window.localStorage) { // Only do this is the browser supports it
        localStorage.loan_amount    = amount;
        localStorage.loan_apr       = apr;
        localStorage.loan_years     = years;
        localStorage.loan_zipcode   = zipcode;
}
}

window.onload = function() {
// If the browser supports localStorage and we have some stored data
if (window.localStorage && localStorage.loan_amount) {
    document.getElementById("amount").value  = localStorage.loan_amount;
    document.getElementById("apr").value     = localStorage.loan_apr;
    document.getElementById("years").value   = localStorage.loan_years;
    document.getElementById("zipcode").value = localStorage.loan_zipcode;
}
};
```

This is the HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Enter Loan Data:</th>
        <td></td>
        <th>Loan Balance, Cumulative Equity, and Interest Payments</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Amount of loan ($):</td>
        <td><input id="amount" onchange="calculate();"</td>
        <td rowspan="8">
            <canvas id="graph" width="400" height="250"></canvas>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Annual Interest (%):</td>
        <td><input id="apr" onchange="calculate();"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Repayment period (years):</td>
        <td><input id="years" onchange="calculate();"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Zipcode (to find lenders):</td>
        <td><input id="zipcode" onchange="calculate();"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Approximate Payments:</th>
        <td><button onclick="calculate();">Calculate</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Monthly payment:</td>
        <td>$<span class="output" id="payment"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Total payment:</td>
        <td>$<span class="output" id="total"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Total interest:</td>
        <td>$<span class="output" id="totalinterest"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Sponsors:</th>
        <td colspan="2">Apply for your loan with one of these fine lenders:
        <div id="lenders"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What does your calculate() function do? I just grabbed your code, and implemented it, and everything is fine.

Comment: I added the calculate() function for clarity

Comment: Ok so I figured it out. I had left out apr.value in the save() section and I didn't see it until I had stepped away from it and re-viewed it when James asked the question. I've updated the question with the correct info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the save() portion of the calculate() function states:

```
save( amount.value, years.value, zipcode.value );
```

It should read:

```
save( amount.value, apr.value, years.value, zipcode.value );
```